# Cast Object To Model Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, object

I want to cast my query result from object to model below mention is the query i just want to show test details in a grid but the grid i m using is of kendo

```
 var data = (from temp in context.Test_Master
                                     join item in context.Test_Settings on temp.Test_Id equals item.Test_Id
                                     join chp in context.lp_Chapter on temp.ChapterId equals chp.ChapterId
                                     join btch in context.BatchDetails on item.BatchId equals btch.BatchId
                                     where
                                        chp.StandardId == stdId
                                        &&
                                        item.BatchId==btchId


                                     select new {item.Test_Master.Test_Id,item.Test_Master.Test_Name,item.Test_Master.Test_Date,item.Start_Time,item.End_Time });

                data = data.OrderBy(x => x.Test_Date);

                var r = new PageList<Object>(data, pageNo, pageSize);
                return r;
```

Controller Code

```
PageList<Object> TestDetails = studBal.testDetails(studentId,command.Page - 1, command.PageSize);
                var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
                {
                    Data = TestDetails.Select(x =>
                    {
                        var Test = new Test();
                        Test.Test_Id = x.Id;
                        Test.Test_Name = x.Name;
                        Test.Test_Date = x.Name;
                        Test.Start_Time = x.StartTime;
                        Test.End_Time = x.EndTime;
                        return Test;
                    }),
                    Total = Test.TotalCount,
                };
```

My Query executes perfectly as well as i get perect results in PageList TestDetails but i want to convert this object to my moodel i.e test so that i can display the records in a grid i dont know how to convert object to model any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the result into a model

```
var data = (from temp in context.Test_Master
  ...
  select new Test
  {
    Test_Id = item.Test_Master.Test_Id,
    Test_Name =  item.Test_Master.Test_Name,
    ...  
  };
```

Comment: but it gives me error  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.Object)' method, when i m trying to convert TestDate to date time

Comment: Are you sure both sides of the equation are typeof `DateTime` (i.e. `Test.Test_Date` and `item.Test_Master.Test_Date`

Comment: yes it gives me date like this in my query Test_Date":"\/Date(1406831400000)\/

Comment: What is the database data type for `Test_Date`? You could try `Test_Date = DateTime.Parse(item.Test_Master.Test_Date),`

Comment: database data type is date time and i m using kendo grid to display this query data

Answer (score 1):

@StephenMuecke answer is all you need if your query is returning the model that your view is using. I prefer however to use domain models that the data access layer can retrieve and viewModels that the views know about

In that case Stephen's suggestions becomes only the first part. Have your query return a list of defined objects (MyDomainTestModel) as suggested by Stephen, then in the controller (or even better in a separate ModelBuilder class that the controller calls), use a mapping tool (I use AutoMapper) or a linq "Select" to convert the list of MyDomainTestModel to a list of Test (which becomes your view model) that you can pass to the view.